# Geospatial order by distance of the relation

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, geospatial

Let's say I have a database of all cities in the world with lat lon point field in database and all countries with lat lon. Now I have Poland and USA "active" (querying only those cities in this countries).
I have a user country set to Poland.
Im searching for "Wars" and I now I have Warsaw In Poland and Warsaw in USA but I want to order it by the distance of countries starting from the country that is set to the user. So in this case first Warsaw in Poland, then Warsaw in USA.
In case there was a "Warsaw" city in Spain it should be ordered:
Warsaw (Poland) -> Warsaw (Spain) -> Warsaw (USA).

Im using Grimzy\LaravelMysqlSpatial package to handle those distance operations.

```
$places = Place::active()->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
                $query->where('name', 'like', $request->q . '%')
                    ->orWhere('ascii_name', 'like', $request->q . '%');
            })->limit(10)->get();
```

The relation of "Place" and "Country" is:

```
public function country()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Country::class);
    }
```

So I need to get the distances from Poland to other countries and order by this value the resulting places.
I would appreciate your help here :)

Comment: Assuming you are storing the coordinates as a `POINT` data type then MySQL has [ST_Distance](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-relation-functions-object-shapes.html#function_st-distance) that can get the distance between two points (among other geometries)

Comment: I managed to do the task by first getting countries ordered by the distance from the base country and then with the:
->orderByRaw("FIELD(country_id, " .$distances . ") ASC")

Comment: I'd suggest changing the `->orderByRaw` to a `->selectRaw` so you can access the actual distance as well :)